# Get country codes of Twitter followers

Tags: twitter, country-codes

How do I get country codes of my Twitter followers using the Twitter API? Or is there any work around to get the same?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

The response should have a location field, like

```
"location": "San Francisco, CA",
```

The data in there is free text, so people can type "London" or a lat/long or even nonsense.

Most people have some geo-data in there.

Comment: link is broken, does the page still exist?

Comment: bit late but here is the page: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show and the page defining the user object: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/user-object